# Gmail not automatically deleting spam emails

Tags: gmail

There are 3,700 emails in my spam folder. Despite the message near the top of the page stating that emails in spam will be deleted after 30 days, Gmail is not automatically deleting any emails. There are emails in the folder several years old. How can I fix this?

Comment: You've only got 3700 spams in several years? HOW DO YOU DO THIS?!

Comment: You can manually delete them all.

Comment: @JakeGould What I'm looking to do is to fix the automatic process, so that anything older than 30 days is automatically removed, going forward.